# Why is a recursive deep equality check faster than an iterative version in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, recursion

I noticed that all the deep equality implementations I've found are using recursion and theoretically the iterative form should be faster. However, it's a bit slower for me and I don't understand why.

Assume the data is the result of `JSON.parse` (i.e. primitives, plain objects, and arrays).

Recursive:

```
function equals1(x, y) {
  if (x === y) return true;

  if (Array.isArray(x) && Array.isArray(y)) {
    if (x.length !== y.length) return false;

    for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (!equals1(x[i], y[i])) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  if ((typeof x !== 'object') || (typeof y !== 'object')) return false;

  const xKeys = Object.keys(x);
  const yKeys = Object.keys(y);
  if (xKeys.length !== yKeys.length) return false;
  for (const k of xKeys) {
    if (!y.hasOwnProperty(k)) return false;

    if (!equals1(x[k], y[k])) return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Iterative:

```
function equals2(a, b) {
  const stack = [a, b];
  let idx = 2;
  while (idx > 0) {
    const x = stack[idx - 1];
    const y = stack[idx - 2];
    idx -= 2;

    if (x === y) continue;

    if (Array.isArray(x) && Array.isArray(y)) {
      if (x.length !== y.length) return false;
  
      for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        idx += 2;
        if (idx > stack.length) stack.push(x[i], y[i]);
        else {
          stack[idx - 1] = x[i];
          stack[idx - 2] = y[i];
        }
      }
    } else {
      if ((typeof x !== 'object') || (typeof y !== 'object')) return false;

      const xKeys = Object.keys(x);
      const yKeys = Object.keys(y);
      if (xKeys.length !== yKeys.length) return false;
      for (const k of xKeys) {
        if (!y.hasOwnProperty(k)) return false;

        idx += 2;
        if (idx > stack.length) stack.push(x[k], y[k]);
        else {
          stack[idx - 1] = x[k];
          stack[idx - 2] = y[k];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

I'm using the index instead of the traditional `stack.pop` approach because it's slightly faster.

JSPerf: https://jsperf.com/deep-object-compare-123/1

The data is from Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript.json

For me, the iterative version is 20-25% slower on Chrome and Edge, and the same speed on Firefox. I tried pre-allocating the stack array and removing the `continue`, but it didn't change the results. As far as I know, JS engines can optimize tail-recursive functions, but this isn't tail-recursive.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: `theoretically the iterative form should be faster` .... where did you get this notion? ... An iterative algorithm will always be different from a recursive one, so which is faster depends on the algorithms. There is no "theoretical" assumption involved.

Comment: You are doing so much more extra work in the seconds one.

Comment: Just curious why you assume the iterative would be faster.  Looking at the difference in code complexity, the iterative version has a lot more branches and memory manipulation.  I don't know how expensive call stacks are in typical JS engines, but your test results make sense to me given the fundamental operations that end up happening at the CPU level.

Comment: I assumed the creating the stack frames should be much more expensive than looking up array indices

Comment: But the stack is an array of sorts. Further pointers are used, so there's no real copies being made on the function calls.

Comment: @epascarello you mean in the userland? The browser should be doing a lot more work for function calls than array iterations

Comment: I wouldn't assume manipulating arrays in JS is faster then manipulating stack frames in the underlying C implementation.

Comment: "As far as I know, JS engines can optimize tail-recursive functions" ... but [mostly *don't*](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-proper_tail_calls_(tail_call_optimisation)), even nearly five years after it was specified.

Comment: no clue why you were using `atob`, and what the 'CloudFlare blocks JSON' comment is about. I put in the same reddit data with `var redditData = ...`, and that worked just fine for me. If indeed CloudFlare blocks something, I appear to be unaffected by that...

Answer (score 4):

A major difference between the two approaches is that your recursive function is doing a normal [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) for the first unequal value while your iterative function is putting all the children of an array/object onto the `stack` before searching into *last* child. This causes the `stack` array to grow much larger than the call stack of the recursive function will ever become, and it does quite some unnecessary copying of the entire data structure into a heterogenous array instead of keeping the values in local variables.

Comment: In JavaScript you could also get performance problems around garbage collection when you create large data structures.

Comment: @btilly Not here though. The data structure is not particularly complex and can be dealt with trivially by the GC, as it simply goes out of scope at the end of the function.

Comment: I have personally experienced it just creating flat arrays that got too long.  However that was a long time ago - hopefully the GC is smarter these days.

Comment: Is that speculation, or have you done quantitative tests with which you can back up your claims? You see, because, if you pick a different data structure, the iterative version might be faster, see jsperf links in my answer.

Comment: @mathheadinclouds I've done no quantitative tests myself, only giving a qualitative answer to explain the differences experienced by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You do a single test on one single data structure, and from that you mean you can conclude that *in general*, recursive equality checks are faster than iterative ones? Are you serious? From that one single test, you can conclude nothing whatsoever. Neither could I conclude (anything much) of any one test where some iterative algorithm wins. There are sooooooooooooo many recursive and iterative ways to do deep equality testing (and other things), and there are sooooooooo many data structures. I did *more* than one test, and my results are, very decisively: ***INCONCLUSIVE***, see below.

But first, one thing:

There is a little bug in your code: you don't properly check for the `null` case. If one argument is `null`, and the other one is a non-null object, an error will be thrown.

That can be easily fixed by adding the following line:

```
if ((x===null)||(y===null)) return false;
```

In `equals1`, put it right after `if (x === y) return true;`, and in `equals2` put it after the `continue`. If both arguments were `null`, then the line before the inserted line does the right thing and makes the code not reach the inserted line, and if only one of the arguments is `null`, then the inserted line will take care of `false` being returned, instead of an error being thrown.

I have to admit that I find your iterative version very hard to read. I just can't understand it, but very much would like to. How does it work? Could you enlighten us, please? Does it use LIFO (last in first out) stack, corresponding to depth first search, or is it based on something different? I really would like to know.

I wrote another iterative version, based on your `equals1`, using a FIFO queue (first in first out, corresponding to breadth first search) - I find that very much easier to read.

And I added 3 test cases to jsperf.com, here they are:

[redditData](https://jsperf.com/jsonicdeepequal-recursive-lifo-fifo-redditdata/1)

[linkedList1Knodes](https://jsperf.com/jsonicdeepequal-recursive-lifo-fifo/1)

[linkedList10Knodes](https://jsperf.com/jsonicdeepequal-recursive-lifo-fifo-linkedlist-10knodes)

All 3 tests use your `equals1` and `equals2` you quoted here (with the `null` bug fixed) and the FIFO version I wrote.

First test uses the original reddit data from your question, second uses a linked list with 1 thousand nodes, and third uses a linked list with 10 thousand nodes.

First test confirms that that your iterative version is about 20% slower than the recursive version, and my FIFO version is in between the two, at about 10% slower than the recursive version.

In the second test, your iterative version is the clear winner, it is much faster than the recursive version, and FIFO comes in last (it's a teeny wee bit slower than the the recursive).

In the third test, the recursive version crashes - stack overflow error, and again your iterative version is the winner (FIFO being about 30% slower)

Sorry I can't explain to you why all that is. A proper explanation probably would have to shed light onto many different aspects, I don't think there is a "singular elephant" explaining it all; maybe it makes sense to add more heterogeneous test cases, instead just one example from reddit (even if that is "real world"...)

And here is the FIFO iterative version

```
function equals_FIFO(x, y){
    if (x===y) return true;
    if ((x===null)||(y===null)||((typeof x)!=='object')||((typeof y)!=='object')) return false;
    var xStack = [x], yStack = [y];
    var currentIdx = 0;
    var item1, item2, kid1, kid2, keys1, keys2, i, key;
    while (currentIdx<xStack.length){
        item1 = xStack[currentIdx];
        item2 = yStack[currentIdx];
        keys1 = Object.keys(item1);
        keys2 = Object.keys(item2);
        if (keys1.length!==keys2.length) return false;
        for (i=0; i<keys1.length; i++){
            key = keys1[i];
            if (!item2.hasOwnProperty(key)) return false;
            kid1 = item1[key];
            kid2 = item2[key];
            if (kid1!==kid2){
                if ((kid1===null)||(kid2===null)||((typeof kid1)!=='object')||((typeof kid2)!=='object')) return false;
                xStack.push(kid1);
                yStack.push(kid2);
            }
        }
        currentIdx++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: "*I find your iterative version very hard to read. I just can't understand it*" - it's quite similar to yours, but using an actual LIFO stack (not a FIFO *queue*) and doing a proper loop on arrays ([not a `for…in` enumerations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)). It does have a weird microoptimisation `if (idx > stack.length)` for using `push` instead of assignment when not reusing array space. On a linked list, depth first vs breadth first will not make any difference since it's only deep, but of constant width. Your bfs queue grows with exactly the same speed as the traversal.

Comment: You do however have an optimisation where you check `if (kid1!==kid2)` *before* putting it on your queue. OP's code does not have that, they put all values on the stack first.

Comment: @Bergi How would OP's code look like if the equivalent of "my optimization" (`if (kid1!==kid2)`) would be added into it? I'd really like to know if with that optimization it could beat the recursive.

Comment: I'm aware that I'm not doing "proper loop" on arrays; wanted to be concise, so skipped that on purpose. I'm not sure if the "proper loop" on arrays is worth the typing effort. Is it?

Comment: You'd put an `if (x[i] === y[i]) continue;` in the first and `if (x[k] === y[k]) continue;` in the second loop

Comment: Yes, I think using `for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++)` loops is worth the effort - you wouldn't have to construct two large arrays of keys, you wouldn't have to call `hasOwnProperty`, you wouldn't index the array with strings. Of course only a benchmark could tell how whether the perf difference is significant. And from a correctness perspective, you wouldn't want `{0: 'a', 1: 'b'}` to be equal to `['a', 'b']`, and you'd probably want to ignore non-index properties of array objects.

Comment: https://jsperf.com/leojiangwithbergiimprovement-reddit/1

Comment: https://jsperf.com/deepeq-reddit-fifoproper/1 adding proper array loop made it a teeny wee bit faster, but still recursive wins (by 10%)

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it (how OP's `equals2` works); you're right, he is putting onto the stack earlier than necessary. I'm only putting something onto the stack if I have established that it's 2 non-null objects which aren't pointer equal. ('non-null objects' test is right after the `kid1!==kid2` line) So, to give the OP's code this optimization, we'd have to add `if (twoNonPointerEqualNonNullObjects(x[i], y[i])) continue` in the first loop, and dito second. But I leave that test for you, @Leo

Comment: (continued) and then, also, if you have established "two non pointer equal non-null objects" before putting them onto the stack, you don't need to do that again when you just have popped them off the stack. I think, @Leo, with that, you should be able to make it something like 10% faster.